# Update Svelte component on prop change a lá React

Tags: svelte

Just recently I picked up Svelte to rewrite some old React library I am using. I've mostly been able to navigate Svelte's idiosyncrasies with solid React background yet now I have faced an issue that I feel I need some clarification for.

What I'm doing is some very basic prop management stuff. I have ComponentA that has a ChildComponentB and I pass down a list of items, `selectedItem` (I've tried a string and an object) and a method to be called when an item is clicked: `onSelect`. Within the ChildComponentB I call onSelect as so `on:click={() => onSelect(item)}` and in the parent I set the `selectedItem`.

ComponentA

```
<script lang="ts">
  // Derived from context but omitted for the sake of simplification
  export let things = []
  let selectedItem = things[0]
  $: listItems = things.map((t: Thing) => ({
    key: p.key,
    value: p.key.toUpperCase(),
  }))

  function handleSelect(item: { key: string; value: string }) {
    selectedItem = things.find(it => it.key === item.key)
  }
</script>

<ChildComponentB {listItems} {selectedItem} onSelect={handleSelect} />
```

ChildComponentB

```
<script lang="ts">
  export let listItems = [],
    selectedItem,
    onSelect
  $: isSelected = (item) => selectedItem.key === item.key
</script>

<ul>
  {#each listItems as item}
    <li>
      <button
        class:selected={isSelected(item)}
        on:click={() => onSelect(item)}>{item.value}</button
      >
    </li>
  {/each}
</ul>
```

But I am unable to trigger a re-render of the ChildComponent with this updated value.

What my problem seems to be is an incorrect way of passing down the `selectedItem` value to the child. I've tried writables and reactive statements but they don't seem to work. I'm sure I don't have to resolve to use contexts for such trivial problem but I just don't know what I'm missing here.

EDIT: Nothing wrong with Svelte or my approach. I guess taking on a new framework you tend to look for more complex solutions when the answer is sometimes a silly mistake of your own.

Comment: This seems to work though: https://svelte.dev/repl/84a77d721d54423fa8c8890ce2632d13?version=3.38.2

Comment: @StephaneVanraes Oh my. It seems I got completely blindsided as I named my argument the same `p` as the argument of my find-iteration. Returning immediately true and not changing anything. What a rookie mistake. Hmm. Well I'm happy either way... Thanks for the demo code, it helped a lot. Can't believe I corrected it to that snippet without realizing it. Jeezs